# Array of Strings in Realm

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

I'm using `UICollectionView` to display various images. I'm storing the path of images in realm.I want to create an array of images and store it in realm with all images in one array.

My code:

My realm Object

```
class cityDetail: Object {

    dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var cityName = ""
    dynamic var descrp = ""
    dynamic var state = ""
    dynamic var season = ""
    dynamic var longitude = ""
    dynamic var latitude = ""
    var imgList = List<cityImage>()
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}}
class cityImage:Object {
    dynamic var imgStr = ""}
```

My function:

```
@IBAction func setIMG(_ sender:UIButton) {
    self.img.isHidden = true
    self.imgArray.append(imgURL)
    print(imgArray)
    newImage.imgStr = imgURL
    citydetails.imgList.append(newImage)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(newImage)
    }
    self.collection.reloadData()

}
```

Function in which I want array of path of images:

```
@IBAction func sendData(_ sender:UIButton) {

    let citydetails = cityDetail()
    let newImage = cityImage()


    citydetails.cityName = self.cityName.text!
    citydetails.descrp = self.descrp.text!
    citydetails.state = self.state.text!
    citydetails.season = self.season.text!
    citydetails.latitude = String(lon)
    citydetails.longitude = String(lat)


    citydetails.imgList = newImage
    let realm = try! Realm()
    do {
        try realm.write() {
            realm.add(citydetails)
        }
    } catch {

    }
    self.collection.reloadData()
    self.img.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Please give us more information. What is working ? What are you trying to do **exactly** ?

Comment: @McNight i want array of path of images function named setIMG is used to get image from `UIImagePickerController` and set it in realm.if there are 5 images the setIMG button will be pressed 5 times and i got the path of 5 images.And the function named sendData is used to send the whole data along with the array of path of 5 images to realm

Comment: If *cityImage* only stores a String which will be the path of the selected image, why not put a list of String directly in *cityDetails* ? Anyway you have multiples options : you can store the image directly in the database by converting it to NSData (which is not recommended because it will slow up your database) or copy the selected image to a custom location and retrieve the URL of the copy.

Comment: @McNight i just want to store an array in realm

Comment: @McNight can you please post the answer